# dojo cometd is never ready

Tags: comet, dojo, cometd

I am trying to setup a Bayeux server and client using Jetty, Dojo and maven.

My issue is that dojo seems to never be ready. The callback in require is never called.

This is the code for the HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
            "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
   <script data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:true" src="dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

      function initFormListener( onNewForm ) {

         require(["dojox/cometd", "dojo/io/script", "dojox/cometd/callbackPollTransport", "dojo/domReady!" ],
                     function ( cometd, io, callback ) {
                        console.log(" entered CometD function ");

                        // Function that manages the connection status with the Bayeux server
                        var _connected = false;

                        var _metaConnect = function ( message ) {
                           if ( cometd.isDisconnected() ) {
                              _connected = false;
                              console.log( "disconnected from server " + message );
                              return;
                           }

                           var wasConnected = _connected;
                           _connected = message.successful === true;
                           if ( !wasConnected && _connected ) {
                              console.log( "connected to server " );
                           }
                           else if ( wasConnected && !_connected ) {
                              console.log( "connection broken from server " + message );
                           }
                        }

                        // Function invoked when first contacting the server and
                        // when the server has lost the state of this client
                        var _metaHandshake = function ( handshake ) {
                           if ( handshake.successful === true ) {
                              cometd.batch( function () {
                                 cometd.subscribe( '/newFormData', function ( message ) {
                                    console.log( "new data for form " + message.formId + " in formData " + message.formDataId );
                                 } );
                              } );
                           }
                        }

                        // Disconnect when the page unloads
                        dojo.addOnUnload( function () {
                           cometd.disconnect( true );
                        } );

                        var cometURL = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + "/VisionWeb/cometd";
                        cometd.configure( {
                           url:cometURL,
                           logLevel:'debug'
                        } );

                        cometd.addListener( '/meta/handshake', _metaHandshake );
                        cometd.addListener( '/meta/connect', _metaConnect );

                        cometd.handshake();
                     } );
      }

      initFormListener( function() {console.log("cometd success")});
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   just some content
</body>
</html>
```

It's not like dojo does not work on the server. It does. My app is written in dojo 1.7.2

Is there a known issue that I don't know about or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you for any tip on how to find out why the callback is never called.

Comment: just wanted to mention that I use FireBug and that it usually points out when something is missing but this time I get no error messages.

When setting a break point inside the callback function it is never reached and the text "entered CometD function" never appears in the console

Comment: I have a strong hint that all the files are present. If I delete dojox/cometd/_base.js I get an error message in FireBug. Which is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use [cometD](http://cometd.org/).

According to cometD's [Reference Manual](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/#primer_non_maven_way), you need to replace some js files of the standard Dojo toolkit, with the files provided in cometD's Primer download.

Use cometD's documentation and you'll get your app up and running nicely and in a reasonable time.